# Use multiple strata for initial_split?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am working with biological data, genes, that have multiple characteristics which I want to have reflected properly in my training and test data.

However, the initial_split function only accepts one strata. Is there a good way to create an initial split of my data using multiple strata? Preferably using tidymodels / tidyverse.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make a composite column to stratify on. We've confined the strata to one column on purpose; the resulting sample sizes can get very small and you may not be able to stratify.

Another approach that you can use (that I will eventually add a PR for) is to use [twinning](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1002/sam.11574) (corresponding [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=twinning)).

If you still want an `initial_split` object, you can make one using [`rsample::make_splits`](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/make_splits.html) using the results of the twinning results.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I presumed people would work on this problem but didn't know exactly what to look for when browsing the literature. It would be great to have a R implementation in the future but the composite column (for simple cases) and the twinning-make_split combination (for more elaborate cases) are already pretty decent solutions.